# Emacs in Qemu under Ubuntu 13.10 META problems

Tags: emacs, key, meta, qemu, kvm

I'm having problems with operating meta+v (alt+v) (actually meta+something) hotkey, what enables qemu window "view" menu. And stuff. So I can't actually work in emacs, obviously. And I can't disable hotkeys in qemu menu. There's no such option.
Ubuntu 13.10.

Comment: I'm not entirely clear on your question, though Emacs does support another keybinding for meta out of the box: Press `Esc` *and release it* before the key being modified. E.g., `M-x` will now be `Esc`, then `X`.

Comment: That's great, thanks, but it doesn't really solve the main problem. It would be good to do something with qemu key bindings.